# How to update (or add/remove) all annotations when using angular-highcharts

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, label

I want to add annotations to a my line chart after the chart has been built. I used [this](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update) example for updating options. This works fine for other options, but not annotations. The following will update `subtitle`, but not `annotations`.

```
console.log(this.chart); // Shows no annotation labels, as expected.
const labels = this.createAnnotationLabels();
console.log(labels); // Show actual labels
const optionsUpdate: any = {
  subtitle: {
    text: new Date()
  },
  annotations: [{
    labels: labels,
    labelOptions: {
      align: 'right',
      allowOverlap: true
    }
  }]
};
this.chart.ref.update(optionsUpdate);
console.log(this.chart); // Unexpectedly shows no annotation labels anywhere.
```

If I add the annotations as an option before I create the chart however, then the annotations show up fine.

How should I go about removing/updating/adding annotations after a chart has been built? I've got one version where I reconstruct the whole thing, but that becomes a very jarring user experience.

My `package.json` file includes:

```
{
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    ...
    "angular-highcharts": "5.2.12",
    "highcharts": "6.1.0"
}
```